# How to use both Java MainActivity and Kotlin MainActivity class in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, native

I have SDK in 2 different lang ie java and kotlin and I am using method channel for both It is working fine when they are implemented individually but I cant run it at same time and I am getting MainActivity Defined multiple times.

I tried to call kt class in java

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.